# Regular expression find replace on some condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that has some illegal characters included in it. For example:

```
"The Reverend Mr. Hooper is conversing with his fianc&eacute;e, Elizabeth."
```

Is there a regular expression replace statement in PHP that will do a replace based upon some condition? The condition is such,

```
if((word starts with  << & >> ) AND 
      (next to << & >> is not 
          (<< amp; >> OR <<&lt;>> OR <<&gt;>> OR <<&quot;>> OR <<&#39>>)))
          {
              replace << & >>  with << &amp; >> 
          }
```

Comment: you can also use str_replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks an awful lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323). It seems you want to put text with HTML character entities into XML where only a few entities are predefined. If it's something like that, you should be encoding your HTML text into UTF-8 strings which can then be stored in XML directly.

But if you need this for any other reason, you can do

```
$result = preg_replace('/&(?!amp;|[lg]t;|quot;|#39)/s', '&amp;', $subject);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim, Sorry i am late to reply. This exactly serve my purpose.